# AS3 targeting controller class variable using string

Tags: class, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm looking for a way of condensing some of my AS3 code to avoid almost duplicate commands.

The issue is that I have multiple variables with almost the same name e.g. frenchLanguage, englishLanguage, germanLanguage, spanishLanguage

My Controller class contains public static variables (these are accessed across multiple classes) and I need a way to be able to call a few of these variables dynamically. If the variables are in the class you are calling them from you can do this to access them dynamically:

```
this["spanish"+"Language"]
```

In AS3 it's not possible to write something like:

`Controller.this["spanish"+"Language"]`

Is there any way to achieve this? Although everything is working I want to be able to keep my code as minimal as possible.

Comment: Why not just use a static dictionairy in your Controller Class?

Comment: Can you expand a little on this?

Comment: [Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) Create a public static Dictionary variable in your Controller. The string you are currently passing ("spanishLanguage" for example") would be the key for an object that holds your desired information. Assuming the Dictionairy is called `languages` you could call it like this: `Controler.languages["spanishLanguage"]`

Comment: Will give this a go. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access `public static` properties of a class this way (assuming the class name is `Controller` as in your example:

```
Controller['propertyName']
```

I'm not sure how this helps to have "minimal code", but this would be a different topic/question, which might need some more details on what you want to achive.

Having said that, I like the approach DodgerThud suggests in the comments of grouping similar values in a ([`dynamic`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html)) `Object` or `Dictonary` and give it a proper name.

Keep in mind, that if the string you pass in as the key to the class or dynamic object is created from (textual) user input you should have some checks for the validity of that data, otherwise your programm might crash or expose other fields to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to utilize a Dictionary object for a set of variables inherited: it provides a solid logic and it happens to work...

I do not think this is what you are trying to accomplish. I may be wrong.

Classes in AS3 are always wrapped within a `package` - this is true whether you have compiled from Flash, Flex, Air, or any other...

Don't let Adobe confuse you. This was only done in AS3 to use Java-Based conventions. Regardless, a loosely typed language is often misunderstood, unfortunately. So:

```
this["SuperObject"]["SubObject"]["ObjectsMethod"][ObjectsMethodsVariable"](args..);
```

... is technically reliable because the compiler avoids dot notation but at runtime it will collect a lot of unnecessary data to maintain those types of calls.

If efficiency becomes an issue..

Use:

```
package packages {
import flash.*.*:
class This implements ISpecialInterface {
// Data Objects and Function Model
// for This Class 
}
package packages {
import...
class ISpecialInterface extends IEventDispatcher
```